# SharePoint 2013 & Dynamics AX 2012: Integration of MS Project Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ms-project

This is my problem: I want to install Dynamics AX 2012 in Sharepoint 2013.

A pre-requisite of AX is MS Project Server. Now, i have already tried to install MS Project Server 2013 and all goes fine. But when i tried to install AX 2012, seems that Project Server is invalid (??) and i can't go on.

Is MS Project server 2013 compatible with AX 2012?

It's the only way, i think, because MS Project Server 2010 is incompatible with SP13. I have found this: http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/104748.aspx, but seems that nothing are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AX 2012 integrates with Project server 2010 [as described here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15671).

It does not integrate with Project server 2013 [as you have found out yourself](http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/104748.aspx).